# Let readers suggest edits from the frontend

Tags: plugins, posts, forms, front-end

I'd like to make my articles editable at the front-end for any reader who visits the [site](http://geekswipe.net/). (More like a wiki). I don't really want to trouble them through the registration process. I have no idea how to dynamically enable a form associated with the article and the paragraph they are editing. How to create a such a function or is there any readily availability plugin that does this?

I've referred this question: [How to enable suggested edits?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90505/how-to-enable-suggested-edits)

It uses comment form to do the job. Unfortunately, I'm using Disqus as my commenting platform. Is there any work around?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of to do this would be to give the users a custom role, similar to that of an editor or author to do this.
You can use a role editor like this to fine-tweek the access that you give them (including just the ability to edit posts):

[create custom user roles](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/)

Note that if you just want the ability to *suggest* edits, you're better off adding a small custom form for users as they will have to be manually moderated anyway, or this can just be the (moderated) comments section on the page, of course.

If you wanted a more discreet 'Suggest edits' button you could start with the following code that I've adapted from this thread: [Show / hide div on click with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019845/show-hide-div-on-click-with-css)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showDiv(Div) {
        var x = document.getElementById(Div);
        if(x.style.display=="none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
<input type="button" name="edit" value="Suggest an Edit" onclick="showDiv('editDiv')" />
<div id="editDiv" style="display:none;" class="edit-form"><form>Your form here</form></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

By default the user can only edit their comments for the first 5 minutes. After that, the user is not able to edit their comment. If you want to change this time period, then this plugin allows you to do so using a filter. Simply add the following code in your theme’s functions.php file or in a [site-specific plugin like this:](http://wordpressgeekhelp.blogspot.com/2015/08/how-to-allow-users-to-edit-their.html)

```
add_filter( 'sce_comment_time', 'edit_sce_comment_time' );

function edit_sce_comment_time( $time_in_minutes ) {

return 10;

}
```

In this code above, we have simply increased the time limit set by the plugin to 10 minutes however you can modify it to anything else that you like. Since the purpose is to allow users to fix small grammatical errors or taking back something right away, in our opinion it is best to not to set the limit higher than 30 minutes.

Comment: This doesn't address the users question. They are wanting to allow suggestion's for editing articles not comments.